# NoClassDefFoundError при запуске программы в cmd

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Только познаю java и сейчас читаю "Изучаем Java". Написал простенькую программу из этой книги - "Потопи сайт", состоящая из трёх классов. Написал в Intellij IDEA, поместил java файлы в отдельную папку и скомпилировал всё это в другую, отдельную папку. Перешёл в директорию, содержащую class файлы, и при попытке запустить main класс выдаёт ошибку:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: anothername (wrong name: simpleDotComeGame/anothername)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown
```

Не помогли даже эти способы:

```
    java -classpath . mainClassName

    java -cp . mainClassName

    java -classpath "jar_name" com.list_of_your_packages.launcher
```

Сам код:

Первый класс:

```
    package simpleDotComeGame;



    public class anothername {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numOfGuesses = 0;

    CameHelper helper = new CameHelper();

    SimpleDotCom game = new SimpleDotCom();

    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
    int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum+1, randomNum+2};
    game.setLocationCells(locations);
    boolean isAlive = true;

    while (isAlive == true){
        String guess = helper.getUserInput("Vvedite chislo");
        String result = game.checkYourself(guess);
        numOfGuesses++;

        if(result.equals("Potopil")){
            isAlive = false;
            System.out.println("Vam potrebovalos' " + numOfGuesses + " popitoc");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class SimpleDotCom {
int[] LocationCells;
int numOfHits = 0;

public String checkYourself(String stringGuess) {
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
    String result = "Mimo";

    for(int cell : LocationCells){
       if (guess == cell) {
           result = "Popal";
           numOfHits++;
           break;
       }
    }

    if (numOfHits == LocationCells.length){
        result = "Potopil";
    }

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
public void setLocationCells(int[] locs){
    LocationCells = locs;
}
}
```

Третий класс:

```
public class CameHelper {
public String getUserInput(String prompt){
    String inputLine = null;
    System.out.println(prompt + " ");
    try {
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        if (inputLine.length() == 0) return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
    }
    return inputLine;
}
}
```